# Using datatypes of each other (2 Header)

Tags: c, struct, enums, identifier

I'm trying somethin like that:

File 1.h:

```
#include "File2.h"

typdef enum
{
   MY_VARIABLE
}ENUM_FILE1;

typedef struct
{
   STRUCT_FILE_2 name
}STRUCT_FILE1;
```

File 2.h:

```
#include "File1.h"

typdef struct
{
   ENUM_FILE1 name;
}STRUCT_FILE2;
```

But the indentifier ENUM_FILE1 is unknown. Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Move the enum definition to File2.h and don't include File1.h

Answer (score 1):

That's an infinite include loop. You can fix this by putting all types in a single header.

Alternatively, you could get fancy:

File1.h:

```
typedef enum
{
   MY_VARIABLE
} ENUM_FILE1;

#include "File2.h"

typedef struct
{
   STRUCT_FILE_2 name;
} STRUCT_FILE1;
```

But doing that would be pointless because you couldn't ever use `File2.h` on its own; you'd always have to `#include "File1.h"` anyway. So in the end you'd still have effectively just one header.